# Dust mass-loss rate from a massive star given a set of parameters?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, universe, stars, interstellar-matter

I've been looking for examples at how mass-loss rates are determined.

I'm studying a circumstellar dust shell ejected from a Wolf-Rayet star. I have some parameters like, expansion velocity of the shell (60km/s), the dust mass of the shell (0.1 M_sun), the radii of the shell (R_in=10000 AU and R_out=60000) and its age (T=26000 yrs).

I was wondering if there's a formula relating those parameters and if they are sufficient to determine the dust mass-loss rate or its dependent on other factors.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You're looking for information on dust mass loss, not general mass loss, correct?

Comment: @HDE226868 yes, that's correct.

Comment: [Cross-posted to Astronomy.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13131/dust-mass-loss-rate-from-a-massive-star-given-a-set-of-parameters)

Comment: By dust, do you mean small (i.e., micron-sized or smaller) silicate-like particles or is this a term used in astronomy similar to how everything except hydrogen is a metal?  If the former, are you looking at dust that has "fallen in" or thinking that the dust originates from the stellar atmosphere?

Comment: @honeste_vivere i mean the former, micron-sized (silicates/metallic iron/PAH's) dust grains. I'm looking at dust that originates in stellar atmospheres and that's been ejected away from the star by stellar winds.

Comment: @SarahMassalkhi - Do you know the dust production rate?  That would, at the very least, put an upper bound on the loss rate (i.e., you cannot lose more than you have).